# Xamarin Forms Maps Scroll Event

Tags: forms, xamarin, maps

In my application project, I have set up a Xamarin Forms Map which centers on the users position. Now I want to let an icon show up when the user dragged the map somewhere to recenter on the position of the user.

Unfortunately Xamarin forms maps only has ja MapClicked event so event when the map was dragged I have to click another time on the map so that the event is triggered. I tried using gesture recognizers as well but somehow they neither work on the map directly nor when I implement them on the grid over the map.

After some time, I thought about checking whether the map position equals the users position and i found this tutorial https://xamarinhowto.com/xamarin-forms-maps-getting-location-radius-of-users-input/ unfortunately this did not work for me either since the code could not handle `.Log()` for strings.

Do you have a solution for my problem? The recenter icon should just appear as it is in Ios Maps when I dragged the map from my position.

Comment: there are alternate solutions like http://mapsui.com which have a more feature rich API

Comment: FWIW, in the tutorial you linked, the `.Log()` appears to just be something the author is using to log the result of moving the map. I see no reason why you need it.